# Why is the log not getting called first in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive like this

```
angular.module('myDirective',[])

.directive('inputBox',function(){
    return{
        restrict:"E",
        controller:['$scope','$element',function($scope,$element){
            $scope.printMessage = function(e){
                // $scope.inputval = 'Enter input here';
                // callback(e);
                console.log('this should be called 1st');
                $scope.onButtonClicked({widgetEvent:e});
            };
        }],
        scope:{
            buttonName:"@",
            printedMessage:"@",
            onButtonClicked:"&"
        },
        template:'<input type="text" ng-model="inputval"><button ng-click="printMessage($event)">{{buttonName}}</button>'
    };
})
```

In the other controller i made the function declaration as

```
angular.module('myApp',['myDirective'])
.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.showAlertMessage = function(e){
        alert('this is a alert');
    };
}]);
```

Why is my alert getting called 1st then my console.log in printMessage , how to avoid this.

Comment: Where are you calling showAlertMessage function?

Comment: @Tyranicangel in another module's controller

Comment: it depends on how the browser flushes the console.

Comment: Your directive code looks fine..I cant find anything there

Comment: @Tyranicangel - I need something like a callback so when i click a button my directive would do something, and the enduser can use the  onButtonClicked() and do something else also...

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: @Gaurav_soni your fiddle is blank. Please update.

Comment: @VinayK sorry , attached is the new link - http://plnkr.co/edit/rWVi9Y907gKMofKd8fkZ

Comment: @Gaurav_soni, Your directive is working as you expect it to work. Replace the console.log in printMessage with alert and check once. Here is the updated plnkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/yD0ORRkhhzRtJ6BfgD7b?p=preview

Comment: As Vinay K says, it is working correctly. console.log(e) comes after console.log('this should be called 1st')

Comment: @VinayK Yes the alerts are firing in the right order, I guess the binding to the view happens in the 2nd run that's why in the other case the alert is shown 1st then the binding to the textbox. Question: is this the right way to expose directive function to external users ?